# $\det(ABC) = \det(B)\det(AC)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are $(n \times m)$, $(m \times m)$, and $(m \times n)$ matrices respectively, with $m\gt n$. What are the most general conditions under which

$$ \det(ABC) = \det(B)\det(AC)$$

holds?

Comment: When $B$ is the identity matrix, for example.

Comment: This is likely related to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula

Comment: When $n>m$, for instance: both sides are $0$.

Comment: It holds for example if at least one of the matrices is a multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: Sure. When A,B,and C are all the same size.

Comment: Point taken, I adjusted the question to make it more relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $A,C$ are generic fixed matrices and that we seek $B=[b_{ij}]$ s.t. $\det(ABC)=\det(AC)\det(B)$; $\det(ABC)$ is a homogeneous function of the $(b_{ij})$ of degree $n$ and $\det(AC)\det(B)$ is a homogeneous function of degree $m$. Then the convenient $B$ are in an algebraic set of codimension $1$ of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Moreover, if we take a generic matrix $E$, then there is $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $B=\lambda E$ is convenient.